# Limit of Inner products.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I had the following appear on an exam, and I can't see why I'm wrong and have no clear explanation from the professor.  My answer is below.

Let$ X$ be a Hilbert space, and let $\mathcal{E}$
be an orthonormal basis for $X$. Let $\{h_n : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a sequence of vectors in $X$.  Show:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \langle h_n , x \right \rangle =0$ for all $x\in X$  if and only if $\sup\{ \left \lVert h_n \right \rVert : n \in \mathbb{N} \} < \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \langle h_n , e \right \rangle =0$ for all $e\in \mathcal{E}$.

(I'm only giving one direction, as I was correct in the other).

Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left \langle h_n , x \right \rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$, then clearly $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \langle h_n , e \right \rangle =0$ for all $e\in \mathcal{E}$.

As the inner product is continuous, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \langle h_n , x \right \rangle =\left \langle \red{\lim_{n \to \infty}  h_n} , x \right \rangle =0$  for all $x\in X$.  $\dagger$

This implies that $\red{\lim_{n \to \infty}  h_n} =0$ hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left \lVert h_n \right \rVert = 0$.  Hence, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lVert h_n \rVert < \varepsilon$ provided $n\ge N$.

It follows that

$$\sup \{ \lVert h_n \rVert : n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \max \{ \max_{1\le i \le N-1} \lVert h_i \rVert , \varepsilon \} < \infty$$

For the line with the $\dagger$ I was marked wrong and told that "This limit may not exist" and then circled the part in red; and I was told this was the only wrong part and I lost full credit this direction (it seems a bit harsh).

Any explanation? Isn't this obvious as the inner product is continuous, we may pull the limit in?  I don't see how this is unclear....

Comment: I don't know how to make "lim_n h_n " red.  Would appreciate the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x$ is fixed, we can take $h_n = e_n$. Then $\lim_n \langle h_n, x\rangle = 0$. To see this, note that $\langle h_n, x\rangle = x_n$. Since $\|x\|^2=\sum_n |x_n|^2 < \infty$, the $x_n$ must go to zero. However $h_n$ has no limit in the standard topology. This is the reason your proof is incorrect. $\lim_n \langle h_n,x\rangle$ can be zero for all $x$ without $\lim_n h_n$ even existing. The issue is that you are picking one $x$ with which to do this analysis, but that it holds for all $x$ allows the statement to be true.

Comment: We don't get to pick the $h_n$ nor do we get to pick the $e_n$, there is no reason to assume they are related nor can we force them to be.  Also, this doesn't address my question, per se, because I'm asking if I'm wrong or missing any details.

Comment: We can pick the $h_n$. I'm demonstrating why your proof is flawed. It is perfectly possible to have a sequence of vectors $h_n$ so that $\lim_n \langle h_n,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ without $\lim_n h_n$ existing. This was the flaw in your proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... makes sense.